# What does this vulnerability means CVE-2020-36460?

Tags: security, cve

The description says :

An issue was discovered in the model crate through 2020-11-10 for Rust. The Shared data structure has an implementation of the Send and Sync traits without regard for the inner type.

What is model crate? Sorry if its  stupid question but I am new to CVE vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crate is a binary or library in Rust.

`Model` is a crate.

Long story short, there's a data structure vulnerability in the `model` library.

**References**

[model crate](https://docs.rs/model/0.1.2/model/)

[packages and crates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html)